# java find if the string contains 2 other strings

Tags: java

I have 2 strings "test" "bet" and another string a="tbtetse". I need to check if the "tbtetse" contains the other two strings.

I was thinking if I could find all the anagrams of string a and and then find the other two strings in those, but it doesn't work that way and also my anagram code is failing for a lengthy string.

Could you please help with any other ways to solve it?

Comment: are you asking if the words can be found in the letters provide or appear in order?

Comment: Yes asking if the letters "tbestse" contains alphabets needed for words "test" and "bet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code, it may help you.

```
public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "test";
        String str2 = "bev";
        String str3 = "tbtetse";
        System.out.println(isStringPresent(str1, str2, str3));
    }

    private static boolean isStringPresent(String str1, String str2, String str3) {

        if ((str1.length() + str2.length()) != str3.length()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            String[] str1Arr = str1.split("");
            String[] str2Arr = str2.split("");
            for (String string : str1Arr) {
                if (!str3.contains(string)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            for (String string : str2Arr) {
                if (!str3.contains(string)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: For line String[] str1Arr = str1.split("") - are you trying to put str1 into an string array where each index has one character? Can we save it in a character array? Just trying to understand.

Comment: yes. you can give a try, but if I am saving it as `String` array then I get predefined String method for comparison, like I used `contains()`

Comment: I tried with character array, but then I couldn't use str3.contains to  find the character in that string. What do I need to change there to find in the str3? Do I need to change str3 also in character array? Is there any array function available to test if it contains that characters?

Comment: yes. `String` and `Character` are of different type.

Comment: are you using `Character` or `char`?

Comment: there is a method comparedTo in `Character` class you can give a try to it.

Comment: I tried doing this:char[] str1Arr = str1.toCharArray();
            char[] str2Arr = str2.toCharArray();
            char[] str3Arr = str3.toCharArray(); But then I do not know how to find the characters in str1Arr if they exist in str3Arr

Comment: `char` is `primitive` type I will suggest you to use `String` or `Character` class for comparison as these classed already have `API` for doing this. If you want to use primitive type you can loop through `char` array of str1Arr and str3Arr and compare both the `char` with `==` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to test whether the letters in `a` can be used to form an anagram of the test strings `test` and `bet`: I recommend making a dictionary (HashMap or whatever) of character counts from string `a`, indexed by character.  Build a similar dictionary for the words you're testing.  Then make sure that `a` has at least as many instances of each character from the test strings as they have.

Edit: Alcanzar suggests arrays of length 26 for holding the counts (one slot for each letter).  Assuming you're dealing with only English letters, that is probably less of a hassle than dictionaries.  If you don't know the number of allowed characters, the dictionary route is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

Make a copy of string "tbtetse".

Loop through each character in "test".

- Do a indexOf() search for the character in your copied string and remove it if found.
- If not found, fail.

Do the same for the string "bet".

Comment: Even though you don't want to optimize too early, you should still think about performance when developing an algorithm. This is `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)`. Actually, now that I think of it, it is worse than `O(n^2)` since `String` is immutable, "removing" a character requires a whole copy.

Comment: Use a StringBuffer then.

Comment: These comments are helpful, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to count characters in both sets and compare them

```
void fillInCharCounts(String word,int[] counts) {
  for (int i = 0; i<word.length(); i++) {
    char ch = word.charAt(i);
    int index = ch - 'a';
    counts[index]++;
 }
}

int[] counts1 = new int[26];
int[] counts2 = new int[26];

fillInCharCounts("test",counts1);
fillInCharCounts("bet",counts1);
fillInCharCounts("tbtese",counts2);

boolean failed = false;
for (int i = 0; i<counts1.length; i++) {
   if (counts1[i] > counts2[i]) {
     failed = true;
   }
}

if (failed) {
  whatever
} else {
  something else
}
```

If you are generalizing it, don't forget to call .toLowerCase() on the word before sending it in (or fix the counting method).

Answer (score 0):

```
class WordLetter {
    char letter;
    int nth; // Occurrence of that letter
    ...
}
```

One now can use Sets

```
Set<WordLetter>
// "test" = { t0 e0 s0 t1 }
```

Then testing reduces to set operations. If both words need to be present, a union can be tested. If both words must be formed from separate letters, a set of the concatenation can be tested.